# Android Studio build tools and gradle version compatibility

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools, android-studio-2.2

I'm using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 with android build tool version 2.2.0-alpha4, gradle version 2.14 and I'm getting incompatibility issues that's preventing me from running my app. What build tool and gradle versions should I be using instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *stable version and not *alpha* :)

Comment: could you please tell me what version number that is? 2.2.0 doesn't work. I get a jbincenter error.

Comment: I suggest to use SDK Manager.

Comment: You can use Android Studio Stable 2.1.2

Comment: Build Tools, Revision 23.0.3

Comment: Gradle 2.14 it's perfect

Comment: I'm really sorry. I meant android plugin. The one in your gradle dependency like classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha4'

Comment: No problem: com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0